# Shading issue on the Mesh

Tags: workflow, faces, geometry

i am facing the issue of shading in some faces in my mesh kinda sort of lines.I have tried the autosmoth option but still the problem presit.The rest of the mesh is quite smooth but in these faces some faces the problem presist.[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: just uploades that file                                                                       https://pasteall.org/blend/baf8a5bb4f6e4aacb5d5c6b50848d615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have edge loops along the existing ones, it makes them sharper:

[image]

If you remove them it will round the shape:

[image]

Comment: thnx but i have to convert it into high poly and for that purpose i have to add edge loops so that they can actualy support the geometry after applying the multires modifier

Comment: ok but why adding these edge loops? it will work fine if you dissolve them

Comment: yep you are right thnx for the help